Why did Malaysia's high-tech export share decline in Y2022?
Recent World Bank data on Malaysia's high-tech exports share show a sharp decline. What are the reasons for such a drastic structural change? Or is it just an error in the data? (I can find no evidence in the structural analysis export flows).


You would need to see Malaysia's exports of manufactured goods in 2021 and 2022 by product and the definition of "high-technology exports".  Either high technology exports went down or total manufactured exports went up. The comparable chart for "Medium and high technology exports" does not yet have 2022 data.

@Henry, thank you for the response. That is the problem that I cannot see that difference in overall structure on 6 digits, or 4 digits as World Bank suggests in "Details" pop up. Such difference (about a half) would have been visible.

You will find similar dips for Korea (Rep) and to a lesser extent China and Japan in 2022, while Switzerland had a big jump in 2022 (offsetting a big fall in 2017) as did Austria.  I doubt this indicator is particularly meaningful.
